# Grouping Regressors in Anova Table for Multiple Linear Regression

Tags: r, linear-regression, anova

I am running a regression on R

```
fbReg <- lm(y~x2+x7+x8,table.b1)
```

I then run an Anova table to analyze the significance of the regression

```
anova(fbReg)

Analysis of Variance Table

Response: y
          Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq F value    Pr(>F)    
x2         1  76.193  76.193  26.172 3.100e-05 ***
x7         1 139.501 139.501  47.918 3.698e-07 ***
x8         1  41.400  41.400  14.221 0.0009378 ***
Residuals 24  69.870   2.911                      
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Is there anything i can do to make my anova table sum all the sum of squares for x2,x7,x8 instead of having them separate.

Essentially, have the anova table look like this

```
                 df  SS       MS         FvAL   PR(>F)
Regression        3   257.094   ETC....
Error(Residual)  24  69.870    ETC.....
```

Thanks

Comment: The usual way to do this would be building a base model with none of those predictors and comparing to the full model. The anova function handles multiple model arguments such as `anova(fullmdl, reducedmdl)`, Read `?anova`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To illustrate my comment:

```
> lm2 <- lm(Fertility ~ Catholic+Education+Agriculture, data = swiss)

> lm1 <- lm(Fertility ~ 1, data = swiss)

> anova(lm1,lm2)
Analysis of Variance Table

Model 1: Fertility ~ 1
Model 2: Fertility ~ Catholic + Education + Agriculture
  Res.Df    RSS Df Sum of Sq      F    Pr(>F)    
1     46 7178.0                                  
2     43 2567.9  3    4610.1 25.732 1.089e-09 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```